# rotate 2-dimensional array matrice

Tags: php

how can I rotate this array as follows using php

```
[1][2][3][4]
[5][6][7][8]
[9][10][11][12]
[13][14][15][16]
```

into

```
[1][5][9][13]
[2][6][10][14]
[3][7][11][15]
[4][8][12][16]
```

Answer (score 0):

The well-known technique for this is [transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose):

```
function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}
```